# Get Exception type + message as string in except

Tags: python, exception

How to get Exception/Error type and message as string?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milano/PycharmProjects/upwork/sync.blue/sb-syncer-2021/temp.py", line 37, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I want this:

```
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

By `str(e)` I get `division by zero` only

Comment: ```f"{type(err).__name__} {err}"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> try:
...  1/0
... except Exception as e:
...  print(type(e).__name__, ":", e)
... 
ZeroDivisionError : division by zero
```

Answer (score 1):

`repr(e)` is an option for a similar output:

```
try:
    1 / 0
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))
```

with

```
ZeroDivisionError("division by zero")
```